# Unable to Import Numba Package Getting Error

Tags: intel, numba, intel-oneapi, intel-python

I had run the test code in the comon  conda python3.8 with these:

```
os.environ['NUMBA_CPU_FEATURES']='+adx,+aes,+avx,+avx2,+avx512bw,+avx512cd,+avx512dq,+avx512f,+avx512vl,+avx512vnni,+bmi,+bmi2,+clflushopt,+clwb,+cmov,+cx16,+cx8,+f16c,+fma,+fsgsbase,+fxsr,+invpcid,+lzcnt,+mmx,+movbe,+pclmul,+pku,+popcnt,+prfchw,+rdrnd,+rdseed,+sahf,+sse,+sse2,+sse3,+sse4.1,+sse4.2,+ssse3,+xsave,+xsavec,+xsaveopt,+xsaves'
```

https://github.com/IntelPython/numba-dpex/blob/main/numba_dpex/examples/sum.py- The issue exists with this sample too.

When I run in intel python3.8 and the time up to 2.5 min and I get the below Error.
**Showing Error :**

```html
 No device of requested type available. Please check https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-oneapi-dpcpp-system-requirements... -1 (CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND)
/opt/conda/envs/idp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba_dppy/config.py:57: UserWarning: Please install dpctl 0.8.* or higher.
warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
/opt/conda/envs/idp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:303: UserWarning: Numba extension module 'numba_dppy.numpy_usm_shared' failed to load due to 'ImportError(Importing numba_dppy failed)'.
```

How can I resolve this error?

I used conda to create intel python3.8-full and test the code of numpy and numba, Ubuntu 16.04, XEON Gold 5220R, without GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are unable to import numba_dppy package, can you please try the below command?

```
conda install numba-dppy
```

If the issue still persists, we can try with a basetoolkit image. Please follow the below steps:

Downloading image from docker hub:

```
docker pull intel/oneapi-basekit
```

Run the container from the image:

```
docker run -idt intel/oneapi-basekit
```

Look for the container ID:

```
docker ps
docker exec -it <container ID> bash
```

Update list of packages:

```
apt-get update
```

Update conda:

```
conda update conda
```

Creating conda env:

```
conda create -n idp3.8 intelpython3_full python=3.8
```

activate environment:

```
source activate idp3.8
```

install dpctl package:

```
python -m pip install --index-url https://pypi.org/simple dpctl --ignore-installed
```

install numba_dppy package:

```
conda install numba-dppy
```

I ran this sample (https://github.com/IntelPython/numba-dppy/blob/main/numba_dppy/examples/sum.py) inside the docker container

[image]